# Property change in designer not updating in deisgner file - windows forms

Tags: .net, winforms, properties, designer

I am defining a user control deriving from TextBox class in Windows Forms.
The user control defines a property IsMandatory.
If this property is set to true I am calling a function which does something to the look of user control.

When I used this control on my Form in design time, I am able to set this property.
But the designer file doesn't seem to change. It doesn't have the code that sets this value.

IsMandatory is a boolean property. Either I set it to true or false in designer, no corresponding code is there in the designer file. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }

}
```

That DesignerSerializationVisiblity setting will store off the bool value in the .designer file.

That said, it isn't necessary to specify "Visible" since that is the default, I believe.  Are you setting it to "Hidden" perhaps?

Comment: TYeah my mistake I had set it to hidden. Thanks. Can we make a property that is not visible in designer?

Comment: Sure - just decorate it with [Browsable(false)]